# selecting nth div (and beyond) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

Say I have a `div` containing an unlimited number of child `div`s.  Is there an easy way to get jQuery to select the *n*th `div` and every `div` after it so I can change those (in this case, call `remove()` on old `div`s)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [":gt()"](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt#index) selector:

```
 // div's 10 and higher
 $('div:gt(9)').show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Typing this out of my head and the jQuery API doc (read: this is not tested), but the first thing I'd do is to

```
$('#container div').slice(-n).remove();
```

Comment: Worked, but I'm going to go with the :gt() selector @Rob posted. Thanks though, have an upvote!

Comment: yepp. the :gt() solution is much better because it does not retrieve elements just to throw them away afterwards. This is why I have upvoted Rob's answer too. Next time, I'll refrain from posting answers I don't *really* know.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you need to do something with all divs first:

```
$('div').css('color', 'red').filter(':gt(5)').remove();
```